# Coping Binary files using fseek, fread and fwrite

Tags: c, file, overwrite, fseek

I'm trying to write a function that will overwrite Binary files. Now I wrote this function that overwrites text files and it works perfectly fine:

```
void myCopy(char source_file[50], char dest_file[50])
{
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    char a;
    fp1 = fopen(source_file, "rt");
    if (fp1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open this file, either it doesn't exist or doesn't contain anything.\n");
    }
    fp2 = fopen(dest_file, "wt");
    if (fp2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open this file, either it doesn't exist or doesn't contain anything.\n");
    }
    while ((a = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF)//While a failure did not accure.
    {
        fputc(a, fp2);
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
}
```

My question is, is there a way to to do the same to all binary files in general without using fputc, fgetc, fscanf and fprintf?

Comment: For starters, reading an [`fopen` reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx) might be a good start. Then continue with the [`fread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt0etdcs.aspx) and [`fwrite`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9t88zwz.aspx) references.

Comment: As for your code reading text files, it might be good to know what [`fgetc` *actually* returns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7sskzc1.aspx), because `(char) EOF != (int) EOF`

Answer (score 0):

Your code will be correct for binary files, if you'll remove the 't' character from `fopen` options string. But you can use `fread`/`fwrite` functions and a buffer to increase a speed of copying. Example:

```
const size_t buffer_size = 8192;
char buffer[buffer_size];
while (true) {
    size_t read = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), buffer_size, fp1);

    if (read > 0)
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), buffer_size, fp2);
    else
        break;
}
```